# Jupyterhub Not Reading Config File

Tags: jupyterhub

I have installed Jupyterhub on Ubuntu 16.04 with conda install. Next, I made it use oAuthenticator by adding the following in jupyterhub_config.py

```
from oauthenticator.github import GitHubOAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = GitHubOAuthenticator
c.GitHubOAuthenticator.create_system_users = True
```

I also added the following in ~/.bashrc and sourced it

```
#For OAuthentication
export GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=id
export GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=secret
export OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL=http://xyz:8000/hub/oauth_callback
export GIT_REPO_NAME=mmf
export GIT_BRANCH_NAME=master
export GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN= mytoken
```

After starting jupyterhub, I was able to get the "login with git" page.
Now, I have configured jupyterhub to run as a service by creating `/etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service` and adding the following to it

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts JupyterHub as Daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=root
Environment=”PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/etc/Applications/Anaconda3/bin”
ExecStart=/etc/Applications/Anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub –f /etc/Applications/JupyterHub/jupyterhub_config.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, I started it using `systemctl start jupyterhub`, but now I get the regular login page as opposed to the git login.

It's probably because it isn't reading the `jupyterhub_config.py`. I checked all the directories mentioned in `jupyterhub.service` and they all check out.

Anaconda installation directory : /etc/Applications/Anaconda3/

Jupyterhub config file directory : /etc/Applications/JupyterHub/jupyterhub_config.py

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Start a Jupyterhub with below command:

`jupyterhub -f /etc/Applications/JupyterHub/jupyterhub_config.py`

In Your case, i guess it must be

`systemctl start jupyterhub -f /etc/Applications/JupyterHub/jupyterhub_config.py`

For Doc Reference

https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/config-basics.html#start-with-a-specific-config-file